# Hibernate Entity Listener for named query delete operation

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager, entitylisteners

For our application we need to implement trigger using hibernate. One best solution we could come to was Entity listerner using Annotation, as we need to listen to a particular entity change.

Every thing works well except delete with named queries, which gives no event.

**Code Implementation**
** Entity** -here we added the listener

```
@Entity
@EventListeners(EmployeeEventListener.class)
public class Employee {

  @Id
  private String uid;
  @Basic
  private Calendar lastUpdated;
```

**Entity listener** -

Listener is takes up the entity modified asd performs the intended operation

```
public class EmployeeEventListener {
  @PrePersist
  public void prePersist(Object object) {
    Employee employee = (Employee)object;
    employee.setUID(UIDGenerator.newUUI());
    employee.setLastUpdated(Calendar.getInstance());
  }
  @PostUpdate
  public void postUpdate(Object object) {
    Employee employee = (Employee)object;
    employee.setLastUpdated(Calendar.getInstance());
  }
```

`@PrePersist` and `@PostUpdate` worked well when I used save or saveorupdate on entity manager. But when executing delete named query, I get no event for `@PreRemove` and `@PostRemove`

I would also like to get an event for delete as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible: `The Interceptor interface provides callbacks from the session to the application` and object deleted via native SQL doesn't pass to session, so callback won't run

Comment: Thanks bellabax , so that won't work . Well i was thinking why would hibernate have the event and callbacks feature , if works for cases where enity gets loaded into session and won't be useful for the other alternative ways of db operation(like using hql or named queries).Surely these queries are executed by hibernate so why not give me a callback .Is db trigger the only option here for named query to be captured ?

Comment: Think about this query (HQL or SQL, doesn't matter): `delete * from table where <cond>`. You are removing object directly from database and ORM, to allow listener, should retrieve all object `@Id` (at least) to allow listeners to run. I think this can have a poor  performance impact on system. I never needed a listener on query and we use trigger for our purpose.

Comment: yep .. on my way to using triggers .. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean if use pure SQL, like `Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("update ... set ... where ...");`, then `query.executeUpdate();`. `Interceptor` will not be triggered, right?

Comment: Checked and find Interceptor will not be triggered in my case.

Comment: So, does hibernate's eventing system work in this case?